# R Paste multiple

Tags: r, command-line-arguments, paste

I am currently taking in multiple command line parameters within my R script such as :

```
args<-commandArgs(TRUE)
arg1 <- as.numeric(args[1])
arg2 <- as.numeric(args[2])
```

I am wanting to use these args within my paste string like below. My problem is that I can only figure out how to use 1 of the arguments and not both (arg1, arg2). Instead of "xxx" that I show below in my where clause (i.e. "columnname1 in (xxx)") how do I use the "arg1" command line parameter in place of "xxx"? I've tried a number of different ways and for some reason I can't figure it out. Should I concatenate two different strings to accomplish this or is there an easier way?

```
SQL<-paste(
"SELECT 
 *
FROM
 table
WHERE
 columnname1 in (xxx)
 and
 columnname2 in ('",arg2,"')",sep = "")
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SQL<-paste(
"SELECT 
 *
FROM
 table
WHERE
 columnname1 in ('",arg1,"')
 and
 columnname2 in ('",arg2,"')",sep = "", collapse="")
```

Comment: Fantastic! This worked great. I can't believe how easy that was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the following helper function that allows named substitutions:

```
SQL<-strsubst(
  "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
   columnname1 in ('$(arg1)') and 
   columnname2 in ('$(arg2)')", 
  list(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)
)
```

where `strsubst` is defined as follows:

```
strsubst <- function (template, map, verbose = getOption("verbose")) 
{
    pat <- "\\$\\([^\\)]+\\)"
    res <- template
    map <- unlist(map)
    m <- gregexpr(pat, template)
    idx <- which(sapply(m, function(x) x[[1]] != -1))
    for (i in idx) {
        line <- template[[i]]
        if (verbose) 
            cat("input: |", template[[i]], "|\n")
        starts <- m[[i]]
        ml <- attr(m[[i]], "match.length")
        sym <- substring(line, starts + 2, starts + ml - 2)
        if (verbose) 
            cat("sym: |", sym, "|\n")
        repl <- map[sym]
        idx1 <- is.na(repl)
        if (sum(idx1) > 0) {
            warning("Don't know how to replace '", paste(sym[idx1], 
                collapse = "', '"), "'.")
            repl[idx1] <- paste("$(", sym[idx1], ")", sep = "")
        }
        norepl <- substring(line, c(1, starts + ml), c(starts - 
            1, nchar(line)))
        res[[i]] <- paste(norepl, c(repl, ""), sep = "", collapse = "")
        if (verbose) 
            cat("output: |", res[[i]], "|\n")
    }
    return(res)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was wanting to stick with the paste solution provided above but I'll keep this in mind in the future. Very useful!